# net:: ERROR_ABORTED 404(NOT FOUND) resources could not found in netbeans 8.2

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, netbeans-8

I am performing small project in SPRING-HIBERNATE. I have given the link of css file in my 
**list-customer.jsp** :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
      href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css"/>
```

like this and i have also given

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

in my sring-mvc-crud-demo.xml file.
[this is my project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX6tG.png)

I don't know what is wrong with this link, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This worked for me**
I have reviewed my link of resource and it was like this :

```
HTTP://localhost:40610/web-customer-tracker/resources/css/style.css
```

so what i did, i just moved my resources folder from WEB-INF folder to WEB PAGES FOLDER now it will look like this : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDD8Z.jpg)

after moving this folder i cleaned my net-beans project and run it and my problem is solved.